# Play an iTunes playlist URL on startup

Tags: macos, mac, itunes

I'd like iTunes to automatically start playing a certain Internet radio station each time I log in. Is there a way to get iTunes to play a specific song (or playlist) upon login, the same way you can get an application to start up on login?

(This is almost exactly the same question as [138070](https://superuser.com/questions/138070/automatically-start-itunes-dj-playlist-when-itunes-opens) except that I want to play a user-defined playlist instead of the iTunes DJ playlist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike's answer worked for iTunes 9, but unfortunately it doesn't work for iTunes 10 (see the link in the comment). Here's how to do it with Applescript:

Open up "Applescript Editor", and write the following script:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    play user playlist "Radio Paradise"
end tell
```

Save it as an application, and then add the app as one of the login items in the Accounts menu  bar under System Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple

> 1. Open iTunes create new Playlist (lets say myRadio)
> 2. Add wanted radio station or songs
> 3. Open Applications/Automator.app
> 4. Create Custom workflow
> 5. From Library choose Music
> 6. Drag "Find iTunes Items"
> 7. In "Find:" field choose Playlist
> 8. In "Whose:" field choose Name is equal to
> 9. Type in your playlist name e.g. myRadio
> 10. Drag "Start iTunes Playing"
> 11. Click Run to check if everything works fine
> 12. If it does from File menu choose Save As
> 13. In File Format: Field choose "Application"
> 14. Name it for example startRadio
> 15. Click apple icon on your menu bar and then System Preferencess...
> 16. Accounts -> Login Items Tab -> +
> 17. Add startRadio.app
> 18. Check "Hide" checkbox
> 19. Restart your Mac

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer works with iTunes 10, because the "Start iTunes playing" action is gone! See http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2565098