# Automatically start "iTunes DJ" playlist when iTunes opens

Tags: macos, itunes

Is there a way to have iTunes automatically start playing the iTunes DJ playlist when it starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually no nice, clean, built-in way to hook into (or be notified of) a particular application's launch. But it is easy to combine launching *iTunes* and starting a playlist in an AppleScript program:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    play playlist "iTunes DJ"
end tell
```

*iTunes* will automatically launch if it was not already running, then it will start playing the playlist.

Paste the code into an empty *AppleScript Editor* (*Script Editor* prior to 10.6) document.

- To use it from a AppleScript-capable launcher (the built-in script menu, Quicksilver, FastScripts, LaunchBar, etc.), save it as a “script” somewhere (usually) under `~/Library/Scripts` (your launcher may have a preferred location).

  You might even be able to find a launcher or utility that can automatically run this AppleScript program every time *iTunes* is launched (I have never used it, but maybe [Linked Applications Launcher](http://alphaomega.software.free.fr/linkedapplicationslauncher/Linked%20Applications%20Launcher.html) could do this).
- To use it from *Finder*, the dock, or an application-only launcher, save it as an “Application” (“application bundle” prior to 10.6) and put it wherever you find it convenient. To start the playlist just launch the saved ‘applet’ like a normal application (click in the dock, double-click in *Finder*, etc.).